# Yii Framework 2.0 One AutoComplete For Multiple Text Input Fields

Tags: php, autocomplete, yii2

I have one database table column, named 'animal'. I have a form in the view page which has multiple text input fields which will be submitted in one time. All multiple text input fields are for the column 'animal'. I have an `AutoComplete` widget which provides all the suggested animal names when you start typing in the text input field. Is there any way to use one `AutoComplete` widget for multiple text input fields in one same form within Yii Framework 2.0?

Below is one input field with auto complete widget:

```
echo AutoComplete::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'animal',
            'clientOptions' => [
                'source' => $animalNames,
            ],
    ]);
```

***$model*** is the Animal model class which has the property '***animal***', representing the column name. ***$animalNames*** is an array of the suggesting names of animal. If I echo this code two times, only the first input field has the autocomplete of the animal names. The second input field does not have the autocomplete.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I just edited my question with code snippet. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried including it in one of the classes and then instantiating it as an object for use within YII?

Comment: I am not sure what you try to say, but if you mean, create a class with the code snippet above and instantiate that class as an object for using in the view page. If this is what you mean, I have not tried that yet. Is there no other solution without creating an external class?

Comment: For the most part, Yes that is what i meant. Try that and check your php error logs to see what you get if it is still not working. Then post your code and we can go from there.